# How can I use an if statement in a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

How can I use an `if` statement in a JavaScript array. Below is the code I have tried but it's not working yet.

```
var today = new Date();

var dd = today.getDate();

var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

var today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;


//--------------------- Begin Of Calendar Event ---------------------------//

var calendarEvents = [

  if (today == today) {

    {
      title: 'Nigeria Independence',
      url: 'http://google.com/',
      start: today
    }

  }

];

//--------------------- End Of Calendar Event ----------------------------//
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can’t, that is simply not how it works. // Please go read [ask], and tell us _properly_ what you want to achieve. `if (today == today) {` doesn’t make much sense as an example.

Comment: Create array inside `if`, not the other way round.

Comment: Have a look at MDN JavaScript [**array documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to see how to use arrays. Also it looks more like you want to know how to use an if statement to populate an array not how to use it inside an array. Is that correct?

Comment: Create empty array first. Then use `push()` method inside the `if` statement to add values to array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Push method to add to an array.

```
var today = new Date();

    var dd = today.getDate();

    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    var today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;


    //--------------------- Begin Of Calendar Event ---------------------------//

    var calendarEvents = [];

      if (today == today) {

        var data = {
               title: 'Nigeria Independence',
               url: 'http://google.com/',
               start: today
               }

    //add to array
    calendarEvents.push(data);
      }



    //--------------------- End Of Calendar Event ----------------------------//
```

Comment: thanks this give me a step forward to what i want to achieve

Answer (score 3):

First off, your condition is always true. So change it like this:

```
if ((new Date()) == today) {
```

Also, the above condition might not work, because `new Date()` is not `today`. You need to format it right.

Secondly, to have a conditional inside an array, use a ternary operator:

```js
var today = new Date();
var calendarEvents = [
  (today == today) ? {
    title: 'Nigeria Independence',
    url: 'http://google.com/',
    start: today
  } :
  "Not Today"
];

console.log(calendarEvents);
```

Comment: As it seems OP has lack of understanding on some of the basics in JavaScript here is the link to what a [**ternary operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is

Comment: @Fran Thanks. :) The link will help the OP to udnerstand what's it.

Comment: what i wanted is a conditional statement to check if a particular date is equal to another date then show the values of title, url and start

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this so that if today **does** = today, then create the array

```
var today = new Date();

var dd = today.getDate();

var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

var today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;


//--------------------- Begin Of Calendar Event ---------------------------//



  if (today == today) {

   var calendarEvents = [
      {
        title: 'Nigeria Independence',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: today
      } 
   ];

  }



//--------------------- End Of Calendar Event ----------------------------//
```